# Bar Chart different Bars in the xAxis

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm testing some charts libs and now I'm using Chartjs and I want to create A bar chart and on this chart I want to make each bar has your on x position value and a legend to it.

Something like this: https://codepen.io/mmoskorz/pen/maPExb, but in this case the chart left space for the other bars.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("mybarChart").getContext("2d");

var mybarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Candidate A Votes',
      backgroundColor: "#000080",
      data: [90,0,0]
    }, {
      label: 'Candidate B Votes2',
      backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3",
      data: [0,70,0]
    }, {
      label: 'Candidate C  Votes3',
      backgroundColor: "#add8e6",
      data: [0,0,45]
    }]
  },

  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'top',
      labels: {
        fontColor: "#000080",
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Only one X position doesn't satisfy my problem:  https://codepen.io/mmoskorz/pen/aPNmNx

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("mybarChart").getContext("2d");

var mybarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['1'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Candidate A Votes',
      backgroundColor: "#000080",
      data: [90]
    }, {
      label: 'Candidate B Votes2',
      backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3",
      data: [70]
    }, {
      label: 'Candidate C  Votes3',
      backgroundColor: "#add8e6",
      data: [45]
    }]
  },

  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'top',
      labels: {
        fontColor: "#000080",
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

I tried to put values to x and y, but not work as well: https://codepen.io/mmoskorz/pen/OrNRXp

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("mybarChart").getContext("2d");

var mybarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Candidate A Votes',
      backgroundColor: "#000080",
      data: [{x:90, y:1}]
    }, {
      label: 'Candidate B Votes2',
      backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3",
      data: [{x:70, y:2}]
    }, {
      label: 'Candidate C  Votes3',
      backgroundColor: "#add8e6",
      data: [{x:45, y:3}]
    }]
  },

  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'top',
      labels: {
        fontColor: "#000080",
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you try scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            categoryPercentage: 0.99,
            barPercentage: 1.0
        }]
    }

Comment: to remove left space - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yGYJKE